# How many ways to put n objects into n bins, with object i not in bin i for 1<=i<=n ??

Tags: combinatorics, derangements

How many ways are there to arrange n objects into n bins, subject to the n constraints that the ith object can't go in the ith bin for any 1 <= i <= n ?  Each bin has to contain exactly one object.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Correction, they are called derangements *in the event that we require exactly one ball per bin*.  That is not stated in this problem.  The answer here is simply $(n-1)^n$, seen directly via rule of product.

Comment: In the event of one object per bin, these are called derangements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: @JoshuaWang  Ah, thank you for a useful response. If you put it down below as an Answer, I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state that each bin can only contain $1$ object, if this were so then the answer would be derangements (as JW comments)

Each of the $n$ objects can go into $n-1$ bins ... there are $\color{red}{(n-1)^n}$ ways to do this.

Comment: Each bin must contain exactly one object.